# Posting information to paypal NVP API - Both sites need to be Secure?

Tags: security, api, ssl, paypal

I have a kiosk application which uses a built in web server on the machine.  I am posting the users credit card information to the paypal API and I'm wondering if it's secure without having a SSL Cert on my end and only posting to the secure paypal site?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as SSL goes: Yes, if you're posting directly to the PayPal API endpoint then this is fine.

However, PCI DSS is tricky, and if you're running a webserver on the kiosk itself then you're effectively accepting card data on every single kiosk. 
Thus requiring you to be PCI compliant on all of them.

You sure it wouldn't be easier to go with something like [PayPal Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/website-payments-pro-hosted-solution)?

Comment: Just by running a local web server that posts data directly to paypal's api?  I know of many sites that do this and don't store or directly process the card data and have no need to be PCI compliant.  I figured as long as you don't store the data in anyway, you're safe?

Comment: Yes. Because you're still accepting and transmitting sensitive information via your infrastructure. Have a look at https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/